# How to compare Models by ID and not content

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5.1.

I have two collections, `$collectionA` and `$collectionB`. Each collection contains `Flashcard`s which extends `Model`. I am trying to do something like this, but it isn't working:

`$collectionA->intersect($collectionB)`

The reason is that while each `Flashcard` has the same id, their pivot tables are different. Ideally, I would like to ignore the pivot table and compare by ids only. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there's a more efficient way to do this, but you could reduce `$collectionB` to an array of its ids, then filter `$collectionA` to only those elements:

```
$bIds = $collectionB->lists('id')->toArray();
$intersected = $collectionA->filter(function($item) use ($bIds) {
    return in_array($item->id, $bIds);
}
```